# Unittest Mock - Assert a mock object is not called

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am new to unittest and mock in python.  I would like to assert a mock is not called.

```py
    def test_check_is_available_all_day(self):
        create_not_on_leave = Mock()
        delete_not_on_leave = Mock()
        create_is_not_available = Mock()
        for idx, row in self.employee.iterrows():
            if row['all_day'] == 1:
                if row['is_available'] == 1:
                    create_not_on_leave()
                    create_not_on_leave.assert_called()
                elif row['is_available'] == 0:
                    delete_not_on_leave()
                    create_is_not_available()
```

How do I assert `delete_not_on_leave()` is not called.  I have tried `assert delete_not_on_leave.assert_called() == False` but this is gave a error.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_not_called

Answer (score 0):

use: `self.assertEqual(create_not_on_leave.call_count, 0)`

Comment: No. Do not use that.

Comment: @Rob what do you recommend?